# ITA Matrix Search - at least one connection point in MUC? "No flights found"

Tags: budget, hidden-city-ticketing, ita-matrix

Is it me (i.e., am I missing an incredibly simple code?), or can ITA Matrix not support my broad search?

My goal is to find a one-way ticket from Hanoi to Munich using hidden cities. For several hours, I have googled various codes that don't seem to work, including: [F? MUC F?] and [MPS:MUC]. (I did not include the brackets in those searches.)

When I use the following search criteria, the result is "no flights found" (the Destination is a list of all airports in Europe). Even when I cut the Destination list to 5 airports, there are no flights found.

Departing from: HAN
Routing codes: MUC
Destination: ABZ, ACE, AER, AGP, ALC, AMS, ARN, ATH, BBU, BCN, BEG, BFS, BGO, BGY, BHD, BHX, BIO, BLL, BLQ, BMA, BOD, BOO, BRE, BRI, BRS, BRU, BSL, BTS, BUD, CAG, CDG, CGN, CIA, CPH, CRL, CTA, CWL, DME, DRS, DTM, DUB, DUS, EDI, EMA, EVN, FAO, FCO, FLR, FMO, FNC, FRA, FUE, GCI, GDN, GLA, GOT, GRO, GVA, GYD, HAJ, HAM, HEL, HER, HHN, IBZ, IOM, JER, KBP, KEF, KGD, KRK, KRR, KTW, KUF, LBA, LCY, LED, LEJ, LGW, LHR, LIN, LIS, LJU, LPA, LPL, LTN, LUX, LYS, MAD, MAH, MAN, MCM, MJV, MLA, MRS, MUC, MXP, NAP, NCE, NCL, NTE, NUE, OLB, OPO, ORK, ORY, OSL, OTP, PIK, PMI, PMO, PRG, PSA, RHO, RIX, ROV, SIP, SKG, SNN, SOF, SOU, SPC, STN, STR, SVG, SVO, SVQ, SXB, SXF, TFN, TFS, TIA, TLL, TLS, TOS, TRD, TRF, TRN, TSR, TXL, VCE, VIE, VKO, VLC, VNO, VRN, WAW, WRO, ZAG, ZRH

All other search fields are left as default except date.

What am I doing incorrectly??? There's no way there is not a single flight originating in Hanoi going anywhere in Europe with a layover in Munich somewhere in between.

Comment: There are no non-stop flights from HAN to MUC, so hidden city is unlikely to gain you anything here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is happening because there are no non-stops from Hanoi to Munich (as Hilmar notes in comments). A search using `F?` means "zero or one flights," so a search for `F? MUC F?` literally means "zero or one flights, a stop in Munich, zero or one flights." That doesn't exist; you need at least two flights to reach Munich from Hanoi.

Instead, use the routing code `F* MUC F*`. The asterisk means "zero or more flights," so it will find itineraries where multiple flights are required to reach Munich (you could use the `+` operator, meaning "one or more flights" instead, the results appear to be the same).

Note that you'd have all the usual downsides with hidden city ticketing, including the fact that you would not be able to check bags to Munich. Whether this itinerary makes financial or logical sense is something you'd have to determine for yourself. In a quick search I just did for a random day, the hidden city itineraries were all more expensive than just pricing to Munich, but results may vary.